# Make pantheon terminal window appear on all workspaces

Tags: release-freya, pantheon-terminal, workspace

Somehow, I accidentally made one of my pantheon terminal sessions appear on every virtual workspace, and wanted to repeat this with another window - how do I do this?

Right clicking the title bar of pantheon terminal only offers "close" as an option.

(I am running multi-monitor setup if it's relevant)

Comment: You have to right-click on the title bar, when the window is not maximized and select "Always on visible workspace". Does this work?

Comment: no, as mentioned in the question, i am only offered "close" when right clicking on the terminal title bar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by assigning a keyboard shortcut to "Toggle on all Workspaces" in System Settings -> Keyboard. Now when pressing that keyboard combination with your Pantheon Terminal active, the terminal window should appear on all workspaces. Press that same combination again, and the option should get disabled.

[image: screenshot of keyboard settings]

Comment: brilliant! thank you! it was disabled in mine so i must have found some other secret method, but i'll be using this method in future

Comment: You're welcome! The keyboard combination is disabled by default.