# How to enable Shutter systray icon in wingpanel?

Tags: wingpanel

Just installed Loki and Shutter app. I know that in Loki the old systray integration does not work anymore but is there a workaround...?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just re-read [How can I get applications to display a system tray icon?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/how-can-i-get-applications-to-display-a-system-tray-icon) and realized my question was invalid.

Shutter already implements *"Quicklists"* or *"Jumplists"* which is what I wanted. The only missing piece was the accessibility across workspaces and I resolved it thanks to the "Toggle on all workspaces" shortcut mentionned here: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/4607/2831

All in all I did not want what I asked but just being able to execute Shutter actions from all workspaces...

Sorry for the noise :)